# Microsoft Report Viewer only displays 2 rows, when 18 are returned

Tags: reportviewer

I've got several reports, all are copied from an original RDLC i got "working"

I noticed today that all of them only show 2 rows of data, even when more than 2 rows are returned.

My totals are correct, for all the rows, so clearly rows are getting to the Report Viewer
as the totall are calculated there using expressions.

Can anyone give me any hints as to what might be causing this issues?

I'd greatly appreicate it.

Cal-

Comment: Ive' googled more again today, my datasource is a collection of strongly typed objects, and my data is hosted in a Table.

are there any settings on a table that might limit the # of rows?
Thanks,
Cal-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

the expression to do row Coloring was also put on the groups for the table.
(click on table, rt click on details (the one wtih three hz lines)
edit group. it was there.

I removed it and it fixed the issue.